# Conditional format formula using =today() and greater than / less than

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Trying to set up a bit of a to do list with conditional formatting dates. Any time I open the file B2 will load =today()'s date. What I'm hoping to do is find a formula that will allow something like if C2 < B2 (Over due) then conditional formatting rule, or if C2 is 7 days more than B2 then format rule 2.

Not sure how to proceed with this as =today() isn't being treated like numeric data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that if **C2>B2** then **C2** is in the future.

Comment: Official help on conditional formatting already use today(), have you tried that? https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: Whoops good catch - thanks I'll edit that. Still not sure where to go beyond that =if($C$2>$B$2) to apply the conditional format. I know traditionally the true/false statements would come next, but what in a format?

Comment: @Máté Juhász. I had not seen that resource. Thanks! This should help steer me and fix the over complication

Comment: No idea what the heck I was using wrong initially but after wiping the rules and reapplying using the tips in that posted guide - it's up and running, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To apply to C2, select it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=C2<B2
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then repeat with:

```
=C2=B2+7
```

and (presumably) a different choice of formatting, though could be the same (in which case a single rule would be sufficient).

Beware if C2 contains time as well as date the second rule above will not work (and not that formatting will only work for 7 days time, not 6 nor 8 ahead etc, only seventh day from today not counting today).

`TODAY()` could be part of the formulae (if adjusted) - does not *need* to bein  a separate cell.

To apply to ore than one cell (eg an entire column) is quite possible with slight adjustments.